# Matlab Solve System of Equations with Quantized Variables

Tags: matlab, equation-solving

I am trying to use solve() to solve a system of equations of the following form

```
eq1=a1x+a2y;
eq2=b1x+b2y;
```

where `a1 = .05` for values of `x<5`, .1 for values of 5

Is there a way to solve for this using solve? As in `sol = solve(eq1,eq2);`

Comment: why are you not solving it analytical? Should be trivial to see if any solution exist and if it is consistent.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do here. Can you please post a real example (with numbers) and what you would like the output to be?

---

I think you're trying to solve linear simultaeneous equations. Assuming that is what you are trying to do:

I would suggest multiplying all of your equations by 20, so that your minimum quanta size of `0.05` becomes `1.00`. Your problem then becomes the solution of linear equations for integer values.

Note that if the system is fully constrained (that is, if there are *n* independent constraints on the *n* equations you want to solve) then there will only be one solution and it may not necessarily be an integer solution. For example the system:

```
1 = 2a + 4b
3 =  a +  b
```

has the solution `a = 5.5`, `b = -2.5`. No other solution is possible.

For under-constrained systems, i.e.

```
0 = 3x + y
x > 0
```

Then there will be an infinite number of solutions, some of which may have both `x` and `y` being integer values. (Or there may be no integer solutions at all.)

Comment: I should have phrased my question differently, the functions are piecewise functions. I figured out how to put a piecewise function in equation form, but am having issues with matlab solve. I am using the following code to piecewise define my equation

eq3 = m-['(heaviside(x)-heaviside(x-1))*x^3/6  '];

I am having issues with that code though, I also tried this method of piecewise definition

eq1 = -m+...
  (0               ) .* (x < 0           ) + ...
  (-2*x.^2.*(x-3/2)) .* (0 <= x & x < 1  ) + ...
  (1+(x-1).^2      ) .* (1 <= x & x < 3/2) + ...
  (x-1/4           ) .* (x >= 3/2        );

Comment: @user1265868: as you can see, StackOverflow doesn't allow proper formatting in comments (which makes your code a mess to look at.) Could you please revise your question to include this new information?

Answer (score 0):

Okay let me give you a quick rundown.

if you want to solve an equation or a system of equations and conditions then you need to define them as such, so let me explain.
so by example

```
clear all; %just to be safe
syms x y b 
a=0.5;
somevalue=1;
someothervalue=3;
eq1= a*x+a*y == somevalue; %this is your first equation
eq2= b*x+b*y == someothervalue; %this is your 2nd equation
cond1= x<5; %this is a condition which matlab sees as an "equation"
eqs=[eq1,eq2,cond1]; %these are the equations and conditions you want to solve for, use this for solve
eqs=[eq1,eq2]; %use this for vpasolve and set your condition in range
vars=[x,y,b]; %these are the variable you want to solve for
range = [-Inf 5; NaN NaN; NaN NaN]; %NaN means you set no range

%you can use solve or vpasolve, second one being numeric, which is the one you'll probably want
n=5;
sol=zeros(n,numel(vars));
for i = 1:n 
    temp1 = vpasolve(eqs, vars, range, 'random', true);
    temp = vpasolve(eqs, vars, 'random', true);
    sol(i,1) = temp.x;
    sol(i,2) = temp.y;
    sol(i,3) = temp.b;
end
sol
```

Now when I run this myself I can't get the range to properly work for some reason, still trying to figure that out. When you don't set a range it works just fine, if you can use the solve function then there also isn't a problem.
In theory the range function should work fine like this so it might be a bug on my end.

If you use solve you have some nice options where you can use assume to set extra conditions that are a bit more advanced, like only checking for real solutions or only integers, etc.