# Solving System of Piecewise Equations in Matlab, keep getting "Function 'lt' is not implemented for MuPAD symbolic objects"

Tags: matlab, piecewise

I'm trying to run this code

```
   syms x m
eq3 = m-['(heaviside(x)-heaviside(x-1))*x^3/6  ']; 
    %...
    % '(heaviside(x-1)-heaviside(x-2))*(1/6)*(-3*x) + ' ...
    % '(heaviside(x-2)-heaviside(x-3))*(1/6)*(3*x^3-24*x^1) + ' ...
    % '(heaviside(x-3)-heaviside(x-4))*(1/6)*(4-x)^3'];
eq2=-x+(.6/.0360)*m;

sol = solve(eq3,eq2);
```

But I keep getting this error

Function 'lt' is not implemented for MuPAD symbolic objects.

I searched and found that I needed to make x a double, so I tried that but instead i get this error when I put in the line x=double(x)

Error in MuPAD command: DOUBLE cannot convert the input expression into a
double array.
If the input expression contains a symbolic variable, use the VPA function
instead.

Error in ==> sym.sym>sym.double at 927
            Xstr = mupadmex('mllib::double', S.s, 0);

If I use VPA, and put the line x=vpa(x) I get the following error

Function 'lt' is not implemented for MuPAD symbolic objects.

Error in ==> sym.sym>sym.lt at 803
            notimplemented('lt');

Please advise, thanks!

Comment: Could you format your code snippet as code please.  See the little {} icon above the text edit box ?  Select the code snippet, click on that icon and see what happens !  It will make the code easier to read and for SO to help you.  And, while I'm here, make sure you don't have any stray definitions for 'lt' in your workspace which don't belong in your code any longer.

Comment: Should look cleaner now, thanks! Also, I have no definitions for 'lt' when I googled that error it said it's because I am using a symbolic variable, and to try casting it to a double. I tried that and it didn't work

Comment: For what it's worth, this is a continuation of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679897/matlab-solve-system-of-equations-with-quantized-variables).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
eq3 = sym('m - (heaviside(x)-heaviside(x-1)) * x^3/6');
solve(eq3)
```

Comment: I want to solve a system of equations, one were some or all of the equations are piecewise defined